# Get correct Date (not system Date) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

JavaScript `new Date()` return the current system date (not the correct date, because I have changed my system date).

So is it possible to get accurate date using JavaScript? If yes, how?

Comment: read it from a server - I think you may have issues with this too though

Comment: Not on the frontend

Comment: Why would you change your system date?

Comment: What do you mean the accurate date? The local system date _is_ the correct date for the user.

Comment: @Bravo Agreed. And this is the best solution for this case. But I want to know if there is any possiblity to avaluate this in client side, If no is there any proper documentation how date is being calculated wrt system date.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum No. In a real world app (my bad app). Where the date comparison done in client side, if the user reste the system date, the comparison will fail.

Comment: you've apparently changed the date on the client side - so how can a browser running on a computer with a changed date know that the date isn't right?

Comment: If the user changes the system date to a date in the past/future a lot more can go wrong - for example the site won't load at all because of SSL certificate validity durations. If the user changes the date to the same value but with a different timezone you should respect that and show dates the user is expecting (or postfix them with the time zone you use).

Comment: @Nitheesh `new Date()` will always give you a 'view' of the current system date. There is no way to client-side know that the value is incorrect. The system itself will also not know that the current time is incorrect.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to code around somebody changing the system time. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You can't generalize that. I recently had to embed a customer service chat with restricted opening hours on a web site and also show if the chat is open or not. In that case, the opening hours depend on the server-side time and not the user's time zone - or even on purpose misadjusted local system time to circumvent potential checks.

Comment: @jarnbjo this is about what you _show_ the user - if your service is closed between 8:00pm and 10:00pm your time but it's 4:00pm locally for the user you can't show "closed between 8pm and 10pm" to the user.

Comment: `server-side time and not the user's time zone` ... which are the same, in milliseconds since epoch  regardless of timezone ... but, I can see a use case to detect a user changing their own system time

Comment: @phuzi This is a generic scenario where the date validation is being done in client side. If the custromer changes the system date, the validation will change according to the date selected. So is there any workarond to detect the date changge in client side?

Comment: the answer below is a good one - you can easily detect if the user has changed the actual time on their system by comparing `new Date` with the returned `unixtime` value (multiplied by 1000 since unixtime is in seconds and JS date is in Milliseconds) - but the browser has access to exactly one source for new Date ... the local system time

Comment: Not clientside no. You will need to fetch the correct time from a trusted server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on the client, but there are several public web services providing the accurate date and time, e.g:

http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin

Replace the timezone "Europe/Berlin" with whatever is appropriate for you.

Comment: By the way, it doesn't matter which timezone you use if you just use the `unixtime` result - that's the best value to use if you simply want to check the difference between the time in the browser and actual time (completely independent of timezone)

Comment: @Bravo—it doesn't matter which of the other timestamps (datetime or utc_datetime) is used, they will both be parsed to the same (UTC) time value so are effectively independent of the timezone requested. The unixtime value is seconds and must be multiplied by 1e3, so somewhat more complex than parsing the other two. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - I figured OP just wants to see IF the date is changed on the client computer - not what date it is

Comment: This will do the trick. My problem is solved.